Is it haram for me to work in fathers questionable business that sells vapes and cigarettes
I am a young adult male and in the past yr Alhamdullilah I’ve built a relationship with Allah SWT so I’ve had drastic character and mind changes. Since this change I’ve been learning more and more abt the deen and after some time I realized that the business my family runs is very questionable and may be haram because it sells vapes, cigarettes etc. Due to this suspicion and unsureness I’ve been telling Him that I will not work inside the stores anymore because I don’t want to work in something haram, now my father may Allah guide him isn’t the most righteous person and he insists whenever we get into this topic that the stores aren’t haram nor are they completely halal and in some matters after some research I agree with him but not completely. In my heart I absolutely hate working here and I fear the consequences from Allah for working here. It’s not like the type of thing where I’m working here as it’s normal or okay, taking the money and that type of stuff. Since I’ve had the character and mindset change I always refuse to work when I’m asked to and I try to give my dad reasonings but I get to a dead end almost always and also to the point where it makes weakens the relationship between me and my father. So every once in a while for example if one of the employees are out and my dad needs help, he tells me to help him, we argue for a bit and he calls me disobedient that I don’t help him or that he spent his whole life working and working to build a future for me and that I end up disobeying him and not helping him. Our relationship gets weaker over time because of this disagreement but to avoid problems sometimes if he really needs help if there is no worker I go work so that I can avoid the problems and ruining my relationship with my father. Keep in mind as well that I am incapable of leaving or going to work my own job because I am in the west and I’m not of capable age. I am taking all this as a test from Allah to test my patience because I hate working here, I don’t take a single penny whenever I work here and I’m doing it to avoid cutting ties with my parents and to avoid problems with them. I’d just like to know is it haram on me and what are something’s you suggest I do. I’m in a really tough spot and lost on what I should do. I always think of these two ayahs “ وَٱعۡبُدُوا۟ ٱللَّهَ وَلَا تُشۡرِكُوا۟ بِهِۦ شَیۡءࣰاۖ وَبِٱلۡوَ ٰلِدَیۡنِ إِحۡسَـٰنࣰا” and “ وَوَصَّیۡنَا ٱلۡإِنسَـٰنَ بِوَ ٰلِدَیۡهِ حُسۡنࣰاۖ وَإِن جَـٰهَدَاكَ لِتُشۡرِكَ بِی مَا لَیۡسَ لَكَ بِهِۦ عِلۡمࣱ فَلَا تُطِعۡهُمَاۤۚ ”
